# Finite-dimensional representations of quantum $SU(2)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

The most famous of all the quantum groups is $SU_q(2)$ - the Quantum special unitary group. The irreducible comodules of this quantum group are very well understood - they are labelled by integers (or half-integers) just as in the classical case. Now I am wondering myself what the finite-dimensional modules of $SU_q(2)$ looks like?? The irreducible $*$-representations have been described [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-139/issue-1/Algebras-of-functions-on-compact-quantum-groups-Schubert-cells-and/cmp/1104203139.full). But what happens for finite-dimensional (not necessarily irreducible) modules. I know that in general the modules will not be decomposed into irreducible modules, but maybe there is still a classification?

Comment: When, many years ago, I took a seminar class on this (based on, e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9603025 ), I remember that many of the modules that arose naturally were indeed completely reducible, in a form very similar to the $q=0$ versions.